# Issue by deleting an item from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this script:

```
import urllib.request, re

sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-15h10-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455588/")
sourcecode = str(sourcecode.read())

out_file = open("proxy.txt","w")
out_file.write(sourcecode)
out_file.close()

with open("proxy.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        ip = re.findall("(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})", line)
        ip[:3]=[]
        ip[-1]=[]

for addr in ip:
    print(addr)
```

but what I don't understand is why at the end of print i find "[]"
How can i remove these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you assign `ip[-1]` to an empty list. If you need to strip the first three and last entry in the `ip` list, do it with slicing like this:

```
ip = ip[3:-1]
```

This will start from the entry `3` and go up until the second from last.